# How to create an alias in a shell to go to parent directories

Tags: linux, macos, bash, ubuntu

I'm wondering how to create an alias with endless arguments for going parent directories without alias name!

Currently I have written this function to achieve it and works perfectly.

```
b() {
  list=$1
  for (( i=0; i<${#list}; i++ )); do
    cd ..
  done
}
```

You can use it like `b ..` or `b ...` or `b .`

The thing I want is that to use it without "`b`", just dots! How can we make it dynamically?

Edit:

Input - Output

```
.. => cd ../../
... => cd ../../../
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want `b` by itself to do what? Go to the parent directory?

Comment: `b` is arbitrary name, you can say whatever you want and yes, to go to parent directory(ies)

Comment: No, he wants `..` by itself to go to his parent directory, `...` to go to the one above that, and so on.

Comment: You would need to create a function name `.`, and another named `..`, and another named `...`, etc.  Perhaps simply name your function `.` instead of `b` and do `. ..` or `. ....`

Comment: @rojomoke Oh! Thanks. I was misreading.

Comment: `alias ..='cd ..'` Define as much dots as you need.

Comment: @ceving, but it is not dynamic, it is static, you have do define aliases for all the cases!

Comment: @AdemIlhan There will hardly ever be more than five. So the objection is quite theoretical.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having n-1 aliases defined after pressing `.` n times, add this to your `.bashrc`:

```
function update_dots() {
    READLINE_LINE=${READLINE_LINE}.
    if [[ "$READLINE_LINE" =~ ^\.(\.+)$ ]]; then
        DOT_CMD="cd ${READLINE_LINE//\./\.\.\/}"
        alias $READLINE_LINE="$DOT_CMD"
    fi
    READLINE_POINT=$(($READLINE_POINT+1))
}

bind -x '".":"update_dots"'
```

It works like this:

```
[thomas@corellia e]$ pwd
/tmp/a/b/c/d/e
[thomas@corellia e]$ .....
[thomas@corellia tmp]$ pwd
/tmp
[thomas@corellia tmp]$ alias
alias ..='cd ../../'
alias ...='cd ../../../'
alias ....='cd ../../../../'
alias .....='cd ../../../../../'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just take the safe but boring route and define an alias for each level of dots up to some practical maximum:

```
dots=""
for((i=0; i<10; i++))
do
    dots+="."
    alias "$dots=b $dots"
done
```

It's not interesting, but it doesn't have any odd side effects either.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
dots=".."
target="cd .."
for((i=0; i<10; i++))
do
    alias "$dots=$target"
    dots+="."
    target+="/.."
done
unset dots target

$ alias
alias ..='cd ..'
alias ...='cd ../..'
alias ....='cd ../../..'
alias .....='cd ../../../..'
alias ......='cd ../../../../..'
alias .......='cd ../../../../../..'
alias ........='cd ../../../../../../..'
alias .........='cd ../../../../../../../..'
alias ..........='cd ../../../../../../../../..'
alias ...........='cd ../../../../../../../../../..'
```